# How to prep a ceiling for knockdown

Tags: ceiling

I have a 25 y.o. ceiling that had popcorn, which has been removed and smoothed. I would like to apply knockdown mud so that it looks like this:

[image]

Is it necessary to prep the ceiling?  Is it enough to broom clean the ceiling?

Answer (score 1):

After removing popcorn I usually find areas that need some topping mud to make a nice even base. After that a damp rag wipe down or a kitchen sponge mop to remove any heavy dust and shoot the mud. Texture is normally put on bare sheetrock no prep work other than filling voids from screws and tape to hide seams is all that is needed.

Comment: In your experience, would you use [bonding primer](http://www.homedepot.com/p/KILZ-1-gal-Adhesion-Bonding-Primer-L211101/204763136) in this case?

Comment: I shoot the mud on clean dry sheetrock nothing else is needed.

Comment: The ceiling is old: popcorn was removed, smoothed and painted: not 'naked' sheetrock. Any experience \ tips with this scenario?  Comments regarding the bonding primer? Thanks